# Can batteries connected in series be treated as separate voltage sources?

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-source

I'm working on a project where one module will run on 6V and another on max 5V. As voltage source, I use 4xAA batteries (so 6V in total). My initial idea was to use a zener diode to limit the voltage to the 5V module, as in the figure below.[image]

Then I had another idea of looking at the batteries as separate voltage sources and using only three of the batteries (4.5V) for the 5V module, and all 4 batteries for the 6V module. See figure below

[image]

Would this cause any problems or be "bad practice", or would it work just as well as the first solution?

Comment: Currently this is unanswerable. What modules those are, how much current they consume, and do they have any other connections between them to even guess will they blow up or not.

Comment: Without knowing what your modules are I can tell you this is probably a bad idea.  If you tell us what they are and how much current they use, we can tell you what you *should* do.

Comment: 4 primary cells (alkaline or carbon zinc) will get you 4V when they are depleted. unless you plan on chucking them out when that are only half used, find a better method to make 5V

Answer (score 4):

In your first diagram the Zener is backwards and is just a diode shorting out the 5 V module. R will run very hot. It would be very unusual not to have common negative instead of common positive.

In your second diagram the batteries will discharge at different rates so it's not a good scheme. A low drop-out voltage regulator for the 5 V circuit would be a much better idea and improve battery life. (The Zener regulator would be conducting all the time and wasting battery energy.)